# windows phone 8 background agent timing

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have applied background agent in my windows phone app and I want my app to run in every 1 min.
for that i have given "FromMinutes(1)" but now I want to pass time dynamically like 
TimeSpan.FromMinutes()..want to pass any minutes 1 or 10 or 15 dynamically

```
#if DEBUG 
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)); 
#endif
```

Now I'm doing it like this

```
#if DEBUG 
//myinput is the dynamic time given by the user, it varies form user to user.
int myinput = 10;
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(myinput)); 
#endif
```

Comment: #if DEBUG
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
Now I'm doing it like this but
#if DEBUG
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(myinput));
#endif
myinput is the some dynamic time given by the user it varies form user to user.

Comment: You can edit your question, adding the code.

Comment: #if DEBUG
      ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif

Comment: the above line  I have added so that my background agent will run in every 60 sec/1 min but after that requirement changes the new requirement is i need to give  dynamic time there.

Comment: `Timespan.FromMinutes(10);`?... I think this is _not_ what you are asking. What do you mean by **dynamically**?

Comment: Timespan.FromMinutes(10); here if I'm giving the inputs like 1/2/10 it's taking and working suppose I'm giving the input like.
int min=04;
Timespan.FromMinutes(min); now this is not working this is a sample example  this timing will change every time so i ll assign a variable .